# tomar token del autorizacion

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Hola tengo una pregunta y no se si sera muy basica, pero tengo un API que trabaja con un token que se genera con un usuario y una contraseña, luego al generar el token, se copia y se coloca en el postman en "authorization" y se hace referencia a los otros endpoint para insertar, buscar, modificar entre otros, si el token esta mal, arroja un error y no se procede al CRUD, la pregunta es como tomo ese token del header para decodificarlos pues necesito algunos datos del mismo, no se como acceder a el, he tratado con req.headers, pero no me traer el hash.....sabran de alguna forma??de antemnano gracias

Comment: El token deberia estar en req.headers si enviaste la peticion con el token en los headers, y el hash se supone que lo debes tener en el servidor.

Comment: ya lo verifique, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existen varios middleware para poder lograr lo que buscas o puedes incluirlo tu mismo a la logica, este es un ejempo con los modulos [express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express), [passport-jwt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-jwt) y [jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken)

después de hacer un logeo limpio y exitoso se debe crear el token para poder enviárselo al usuario logeado y que utilice ese token para que a la hora de hacer peticiones al back el token haga referencia a ese usuario y darle ciertos permisos,

1. Primero creamos el token, esta función recibe como parámetro el id del usuario y retorna un token firmado para que el cliente lo envíe cada vez que vaya hacer una peticion.

   ```
   import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'
   function CreateToken(_id) {
     return jwt.sign({ _id }, "secret");
   }
   ```

---

2. Una vez el back comience a dar tokens, debe crear una estrategia para poder decifrar el token que le llegue, una forma de hacerlo es mediente `passport-jwt`, passport utiliza las Strategy que se denominan estrategias para autenticar solicitudes. Las estrategias van desde verificar un nombre de usuario y una contraseña, autenticación delegada mediante [OAuth](http://oauth.net/) o autenticación federada mediante [OpenID](http://openid.net/), antes de pedir a `Passport` que autentique una solicitud, se debe configurar la strategy (o estrategias) utilizadas por una aplicación.

   ```
   const {ExtractJwt} = require("passport-jwt")
   const opts: StrategyOptions = {
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      secretOrKey: config.jwtSecret
   };
   export default new Strategy(opts, async (payload: any, done) => {
     try {
       const user = await User.findById(payload.id);
       if (user) {
         return done(null, user);
       }
        return done(null, null);
      } catch (error) {
       console.log(error);
      }
   });
   ```

lo que se hace aca mediante la estrategia, recibir un payload, que contiene toda la informacion del token, buscamos el usuario con ese id, y se hace una comprobacion de si hay usaurio o no, si lo hay lo retornamos de lo contrario retornamos null.

3.Una vez creada la estrategia, vamos a poder utilizar este middleware en cada endpoint que necesite autorizacion para poder hacer peticiones, pero primero se debe inicializar passport

```
const authenticate = require("./strategy")
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.get("/frinds", passport.authenticate(authenticate, { session: false }), FriendController)
```

de esta manera pudes utilizar tranquilamente los datos del usuario desde el objeto `req.user`.

Obviamente este es un ejemplo sencillo, cabe aclarar que los tokens no son muy seguros ya que cualquiera con conocimiento puede acceder a ellos, trata de no enviar información sensible mediante ellos, siempre aconsejo leer las documentaciones, así que espero que lo hagas para que te pueda ayudar mas a profundidad, saludos.